# Sql Query to get number of floors

Tags: sql

I am working on a hotel management software and I need to display floors and the rooms on that floor......

I have a wing_master table in the database with following columns -:
wing_id,
wing_name,
floor,
floor_room_count,
status

Its like I have a record for one wing in that hotel which has 4 floors, but when I write a query to get the floors in that wing it just gives me "4" as the result in sql.....

I want the query to return it as follows -:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want it this way so that I can use nested data-list control in asp.net....

My query is "`select floors from wing_master where wing_id = 1`"

Comment: Table structure and content example would be helpful.

Comment: the query looks ok. there is something else wrong that you are not showing. For example we do not know what data are in the database or how you determine that the result is just "4".

Comment: @zespri, I think the idea is to derive a list of all floors from the number of floors.

Comment: @dan1111: if this is the case this is better be done in the asp.net code not on the database side.

Comment: @zespri, perhaps that would be better for this specific application (since it is to create a data-list control), but being able to do it in SQL is certainly useful: if you wanted to use the results in further queries, you would want to keep it all on the database side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most databases (not MySQL), you can use a recursive query to obtain all floors:

```
with all_floors as (
   select floors from wing_master where wing_id = 1
      union all
   select floors - 1 as floors from all_floors 
      where floors > 1
)
select * from all_floors order by floors;
```

[SQLFiddle example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ff26/2)

In MySQL, the easiest way would be to create a numbers table that has a sequence of numbers up to the highest possible floor.  Then join to that table to get all floors:

```
select num from wing_master
   join numbers on 
       wing_id = 1 and 
       num <= floors;
```

[SqlFiddle example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89d6d/2)

Comment: Hi dan1111, I tried running your query but it gives following error "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "floor" of recursive query "all_floors"."

Comment: @abbas25, hmm, is your "floors" column set as a character field?  If so, you should change it to integer.  In any case, however, you should be able to solve that problem by casting to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is ok, and also it seems that query and table structure will be fulfilling your requirements. can you show your data, because as per the structure, there should be four rows in the table, showing floor 1, 2, 3, 4

something like this

```
floor    wing_id
  1         1
  2         1
  3         1
  4         1
```

If that is how your data looks, then your query must be ok, else there is some other issue. so do share your structure with few rows of data.